# ODBC - Multiple Issues with Connections

Tags: sql, ms-access, jdbc-odbc, sql-workbench-j

I am trying to create an ODBC link within the control panel, administative tools, ODBC connections...

"I will say before I go any further that I have tried using the ODBCad.exe in both system32 and SysWOW64 to resolve this issue to no avail."

Under the User DSN tab I am clicking ADD, choosing 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) populating the Datasource name as 'ACDBTEST', i'm not entering a description.

I am then clicking the button 'Select' and the file location that I am choosing (where the 'ACCESS' database I want to establish the link to is 'L:\Operations Database\OPS\OPS_be.accdb'

I click o.k and it creates the 'link' so I believe all is working as it should be, however...

I am trying to make a connection to this mapped location using two different systems; 
 - SQL Workbench/J

Using this system I have chosen two different drivers;

1) Access (sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver)
and am populating the URL field as

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<L:\Operations Database\OPS\OPS_be.accdb>;DriverID=22;READONLY=true;
```

when I then try to connect I am presented with the message

```
Driver did not return a connection for url=Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<L:\Operations Database\OPS\OPS_be.accdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true;
```

- Apatar

This simply asks for my file location, 'L:\Operations Database\OPS\OPS_be.accdb' I then hit next and am presented with an error stating

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Now I do not know what I am doing wrong and why I cannot simply create a connection to an access database, I truly don't.

Has anyone a guide or thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Thank you, in advance

Richard

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created your User DSN named ACDBTEST then all you need in the URL field of the SQL Workbench/J connection profile is

```
jdbc:odbc:ACDBTEST
```

[image: profile.png]